# Regular Expression in Ruby - Extract Word

Tags: r, ruby, regex

I have the following text already solved in R.
Do anyone know how to write it in Ruby?

```
text <- 'have a nice day, @hello, mr burs'
x <- gsub('.*(@\\w+).*', '\\1', text)
x

[1] "@hello"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: can you describe what exactly you want to do, in plain text?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Make an effort to convert it yourself, and if you run into difficulties you can include your effort and ask a specific question. If you can't get started at all, consider hiring a contractor to do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'have a nice day, @hello, mr burs'
s =~ /.*(@\w+).*/   # match
$~[1]               # this will return "@hello"
# $~ means "the last regexp match", a `MatchData` instance. And we can get matched group by index.
```